# Using Fetch with Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, fetch-api

Hi this is likely a very rookie mistake, but does anyone know why this is console.logging undefined? When i submit url to browser I get valid json response. Thanks

```
      fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API KEY HERE]&location=49.246292,-123.116226&radius=500000')
        .then((resp) => {
          resp.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Did you put your API key in your actual test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've decided to wrap the arrow function body in curly braces you need to specifically return the data instead:

```
.then((resp) => {
  return resp.json();
})
```

Alternatively remove the curly braces:

```
.then(resp => resp.json())
```

Comment: K I see.....so it wasnt returning anything back from the promise.....cheers